Ubuntu terminal sudo password not persisting
Is it possible that the same opened terminal (default in ubuntu) will ask for the sudo password from time to time after being provided a password at some point?.
E.g.:
  $ sudo service my_service_name restart
  [sudo] password for my_username:
  $ sudo service my_service_name restart
  $ sudo service my_service_name restart
  [sudo] password for my_username: <-- again asking for password



Just to confirm, you want the terminal to ask you for the password every time you use sudo, and not remember that you entered the password a while ago?

No, I am used to the terminal persisting the password until it is closed. I just want to understand if the system is behaving as it should

In Ubuntu, the default sudo timeout is 15 minutes. If you think 15 minutes is too short or too long, you can change it by editing /etc/sudoers and adding this line there, 5 is the new timeout value in minutes:
Defaults timestamp_timeout=5


If you specify 0, you will always be asked for password.
If you specify a negative value, the timeout will never expire.
The timeout may include a fractional component if minute granularity is insufficient, for example 2.5.

To edit /etc/sudoers, I highly recommend using sudo visudo instead of editing the file directly. visudo runs sanity checks and tests for parse errors, preventing you from locking yourself out of sudo.
